# Add a global variable to the scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build the User Interface of a game, and AngularJS seems to be perfect for that matter. All my game is inside the global variable `ig`. `ig` looks like this :

```
ig = { money: 100, lives: 3, ... };
```

I'd like to add `ig.money` and `ig.live` to the scope of the controller, so it automatically updates the UI when the variable change within the game.

I tried :

```
$scope.$watch('ig.money', function() { $scope.money = ig.money; });
```

but it doesn't work. It says that `ig` is null. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Its not clear where and How you have defined your global variable.*

Assuming that you have defined your variable as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ig = { money: 100, lives: 3, ... };
</script>
```

To Access these variables in Angular controller you have to inject `$window` into your controller to access your window-bound variables.

```
app.controller('AppController',[
    '$scope',
    '$window',
    function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.ig = $window.ig;
    }
]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my game, but work on a simple test I made : http://jsfiddle.net/X374y/ . In my game, the template is updated only when I call the test() function. I'll investigate this, but your answer is valid. Thank you!

Comment: I managed to reproduced what is happening on my game : http://jsfiddle.net/L5AB9/ . This time the money is not updated by any angular method (like my game). And I have to press the TEST button for the template to be updated. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

or that would be more angular way:

```
app.value('myGame',ig)
app.controller('AppController',[
    '$scope',
    '$window',
    function($scope,myGame) {
      $scope.ig = myGame;
    }
]);
```

or you could put your game in a constant  or provider or factory or service

[module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module)

it's up to you choice the way that better fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

A clean way is to put all your game data in an Angular Service which is a singleton. Any changes to the data can then be broadcasted to controllers that can act on that event. Via dependency injection you can make your service with the game data easily accessible to all controllers. There is a great [blogpost](http://kirkbushell.me/when-to-use-directives-controllers-or-services-in-angular/) that gives a straightforward example on how to do this.